# Object reference error at login control

Tags: c#, asp.net, nullreferenceexception

I have a login control with additional steps (First Name and Last Name). The code is this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>CreateUserWizard Extra</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:CreateUserWizard 
    id="CreateUserWizard1"
    OnCreatedUser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser"
    Runat="server" >
    <WizardSteps>
    <asp:WizardStep>
        <asp:Label
            id="lblFirstName"
            Text="First Name:"
            AssociatedControlID="txtFirstName"
            Runat="server" />
        <br />    
        <asp:TextBox
            id="txtFirstName"
            Runat="server" />
        <br /><br />
        <asp:Label
            id="lblLastName"
            Text="Last Name:"
            AssociatedControlID="txtLastName"
            Runat="server" />
        <br />    
        <asp:TextBox
            id="txtLastName"
            Runat="server" />
    </asp:WizardStep>
    <asp:CreateUserWizardStep />
    </WizardSteps>    
</asp:CreateUserWizard>    
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And in the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Configuration;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateUserProfile(CreateUserWizard1.UserName, txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text);
    }

    private void CreateUserProfile(string userName, string firstName, string lastName)
    {
    string conString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UserProfiles"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT UserProfiles (UserName,FirstName,LastName) VALUES (@UserName,@FirstName,@LastName)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", firstName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lastName);
    using (con)
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
}
```

But when I run the website I get the next error:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


Line 13:     private void CreateUserProfile(string userName, string firstName, string lastName)
Line 14:     {
Line 15:         string conString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UserProfiles"].ConnectionString;
Line 16:         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
Line 17:         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT UserProfiles (UserName,FirstName,LastName) VALUES (@UserName,@FirstName,@LastName)", con);

Source File: c:\Users\User\Desktop\Vivilove\CreateUserWizardExtra.aspx    Line: 15
```

I don´t know what´s happening. Help please...

Comment: Does UserProfiles exist as a connection string name in your web.config?

Comment: if you  haven't noticed, your insert statement is missing "into" keyword. It however doesn't relate to this exception rather it would be an sqlexception..

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 3):

Given the error message, I suspect this is the line that's throwing the exception:

```
string conString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UserProfiles"].ConnectionString;
```

... which would certainly give a `NullReferenceException` if you didn't have a connection string for `UserProfiles` configured. The `ConnectionStrings["UserProfiles"]` part will return `null`, and then when you dereference that for the `ConnectionString` property, that will throw the exception.

You haven't shown your configuration file, but that's the first thing to check - look in your ConnectionStrings section, and check for a value for the *exact* name `UserProfiles` (there could be a subtle typo, such as `UserProfile`).

Comment: You´re right. I forgot the ConnectionString in the web.config file: <?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration> 

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="UserProfiles" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\UserProfilesDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>    
  </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>

</configuration> Sorry if my question is very simple, I´m a novice. Your answer really helped me. Thank you :D